# Accessing nth-child using id in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, google-code-prettify

I am trying to color specific lines using code-prettify. I am getting data from my backend in terms of line numbers and want to highlight them.
If I write this in my css file:

```
#file2 li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+11) {
        background: #18b478;
    }
```

it's working fine. But, I cant figure out how to implement this using angular, where I want to dynamically do changes to the CSS according to the line numbers I am getting. This is what I have tried:

```
$("#file2 li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+11)").css('background', "#18b478");
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <pre>
        <code class="prettyprint linenums" id="file1">***some code***</code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Using angular usually means don't use jQuery

Comment: hope li:nth-child(n+1) select every li. i am little bit confused about this selector!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the line colors in an array. (With a length of the line count) And you have your lines in another array.

```
$scope.lines = linesarray
$scope.colors = colorsarray
```

in the code

```
<pre>
    <code ng-repeat="line in $scope.lines">
        Line content: {{ line }}
        Line number is: {{ $index }}
        Associated color is: {{ colors[$index] }}
    </code>
    //make use of the $index that returns current index of the ng-repeat loop
</pre>
```

Hope this helps!